# How can I add child records to parent entity in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm learning EF Core, and am putting together a simple application.

I'm getting this exception:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

My code:

```
public GetEmployeeDto GetById(int id)
{
    return _dbContext.Employees
                     .Where(e => e.Id == id)
                     .Include(d => d.Dependents)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
}

// this is the error code block
public void Add(int employeeId, GetDependentDto newDependent) 
{
    var employee = GetById(employeeId);
    employee.Dependents.Add(newDependent);

    // exception thrown here
    _dbContext.SaveChanges(); 
}

public class GetEmployeeDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    [Precision(18, 2)]
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GetDependentDto> Dependents { get; set; } = new List<GetDependentDto>();
}

public class GetDependentDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Relationship Relationship { get; set; }
}
```

SQL code

```
Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@p5='?' (DbType = Int32), @p0='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (DbType = Int32), @p3='?' (Size = 4000), @p4='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE [Dependents] SET [DateOfBirth] = @p0, [FirstName] = @p1, [GetEmployeeDtoId] = @p2, [LastName] = @p3, [Relationship] = @p4
OUTPUT 1
WHERE [Id] = @p5;
```

Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Salary] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dependents]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Relationship] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GetEmployeeDtoId] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Dependents] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Dependents] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Dependents_Employees_GetEmployeeDtoId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([GetEmployeeDtoId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employees] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Dependents] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Dependents_Employees_GetEmployeeDtoId]
GO
```

Page model:

```
namespace WebApp.Pages.Employees
{
    public class DetailsModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;

        [BindProperty]
        public GetDependentDto Dependent { get; set; }
        public GetEmployeeDto Employee { get; set; }

        public DetailsModel(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
        {
            _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        }

        public void OnGet(int id)
        {
            Employee = _employeeRepository.GetById(id);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult OnPost(int id)
        {            
            _employeeRepository.Add(id, Dependent);

            return RedirectToPage();
        }
    }
}
```

DB is SQL Server `(localdb)`. Database was created with migrations / seeding using the above DTOs.

I'm following what looks like the accepted pattern. I'm pulling the `GetEmployeeDto` from the database so it can be tracked. I'm modifying the `Dependents` collection in the tracked object.

I'm following the guidance from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#mix-of-new-and-existing-entities), which I'm not sure is the correct model to follow.

The SQL which is generated is trying to `UPDATE` a record in the child table, but instead it should be doing an `INSERT`.

I've tried various combinations of `employee.Update()`, `employee.Dependents.Update()`, retrieving the `Employee` without dependents. All results in the same exception.

Inserting a child record seems like it should be trivial, but I've been stuck on this for a couple of days now. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: You have a primary key so code first searches for the key.  If it finds the key it is updating.  Will only add when the key is not found.  When you have a key you can only have one row in database with each key.

Comment: That's the issue.  I'm trying to insert a new child record, but EF is trying to update a record that does not exist.

Comment: Most likely, you are adding a GetDependentDto that already has an Id.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I hadn't noticed that.  My OnPost(int id) method is populating GetDependentDto.Id with the id for the parent employee.

Comment: What's the content of the `newDependent` variable?

Comment: Your id is matching a record in the database.  How can you update something that does not exist?

Comment: @GertArnold All the values from the <form>, except the ID, which should auto-generate.  Instead, it is using the ID from the URI: page "/Employees/{id}"

Comment: So... what's the content of the `newDependent` variable?

Answer (score 0):

The entity which is attempting to be inserted has the ID populated with [BindProperty].  This is causing EF to attempt to update the record.  Since it has its identity Property populated, it assumes an UPDATE, rather than INSERT.

To prevent a Property from being bound, the property can be decorated with [BindNever] which will prevent this property from being bound.

```
public class GetDependentDto
{
    [BindNever]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Relationship Relationship { get; set; }
}
```